# substituting "that is" with a comma

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, optional-that

> Her necklace is made of gems from the Collin island girt with minerals

Is this sentence as such correct with respect to grammar and punctuation?

Should there be a comma next to "island?"

> Her necklace is made of gems from the Collin island, girt with minerals.

Or, should I rewrite it with a "that is" next to "island" as below:

> Her necklace is made of gems from the Collin island that is girt with minerals

Answer (score 1):

I would write it with "that is" after "island". Otherwise it sounds as if the *necklace* is girt with minerals.

If Collin Island is the name of an island, we wouldn't say "**the** Collin island" and both words would start with capital letters: "gems from Collin Island". If it *isn't* the name, what does "the Collin islands" mean?

By the way, "girt" - the past participle of the verb "to gird" - is rarely used nowadays. Not all English-speakers would know it.

Comment: When "island" and "girt with minerals" are not separated by comma, doesn't it mean that the minerals are attributed to "islands" and not necklances?

Comment: Yes it does. That's what I understood it to mean. It _could_ mean each gem on the necklace is surrounded by minerals, but it's unusual to mention them as gems are _generally_ set in _some_ sort of mineral: silver or whatever. Please tell me what "the Collin island" means. Is there really no capital i in "island"?

Comment: It is a fictitious island. You are saying that It should be written as "Collin Islands" Am I right? Also that the article "the" is not needed before its name?

Comment: Sorry! I accidentally made island "island**s**". Yes - it should be written as "Collin Island", without "the". Some islands are simply named "Bali", "Cyprus" etc. Others are named "Ellis Island", "Bird Island" etc. Some in the UK are named "Isle of Man", "Isle of Wight" etc.

Comment: So we still don't know which is girt with minerals: the necklace or the island. Do **you** know?

Comment: The island is the one girt with minerals

Comment: OK. Then it's "Her necklace is made of gems from Collin Island, which is girt with minerals." Note the capital 'i' in Island. The comma isn't obligatory, but in prose we would use on there. Perhaps in a poem you might leave it out. I'm sorry that "which is" makes it more prosaic. It does make the meaning clear though. It's an interesting line. Where is it from? Is it a poem? Sorry it's taken three days to solve your puzzle!

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. Yes, it is from an unpublished prose poetry. Why use which, and not that?

Comment: Hi Ammu. There are two types of relative clause: _defining_ relative clauses and _non-defining_ relative clauses. As it says [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/relative-clauses-non-defining-relative-clauses), "We always use a relative pronoun or adverb to start a non-defining relative clause: who, which, whose, when or where (but not that). We also use commas to separate the clause from the rest of the sentence."

Comment: We would use '**that**' to specify a particular island. Read about **defining** relative clauses [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses). So you need a **non-defining** one. Hope this helps. Good luck with the prose poem. I wish I could read it.

Comment: By the way, my original answer suggested using "that" because it seemed you were specifying a _particular_ island in a group of islands.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to say this would be:

Her necklace is made of gems from the Collin island that (or which) have been girt with minerals.

But if you would like to say it without "that", you don't need a "," there.

Comment: I guess, if we remove "that" Collin islands shouldn't have an article "the" before it. (going by Brixtonian's suggestion) What do you think?